# CommandParameter binding not updated

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The following code shows a *ListView* which ItemSource is an *ObservableCollection* of the *PageModel*. It's items have ContextActions to edit or delete them.

```xml
<!--BindingContext = new PageModel()-->
<ListView x:Name="itemList" ItemSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTamplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Title} Detail="{Binding Index, StringFormat='{0}'}">
                <TextCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem
                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference itemList}, Path=BindingContext.EditCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}
                        Text="Edit" />
                    <MenuItem
                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference itemList}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}
                        IsDestructive="True"
                        Text="Delete" />
                </TextCell.ContextActions>
            </TextCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

```cs
class PageModel {
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
    public ICommand EditCommand { get; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }

    public PageModel() {
        this.EditCommand = new Command<Item>(EditItem);
        this.DeleteCommand = new Command<Item>(DeleteItem);

        this.Items = new ObservableCollection {
            new Item(0, "Item 1"),
            new Item(1, "Item 2"),
            new Item(2, "Item 3")
        }
    }

    private void EditItem(Item item) {
        this.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        this.Items.Insert(item.Index, new Item(item.Index. "Changed Title"));
    }
    private void DeleteItem(Item item) {
        this.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}

class Item {
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // Constructor ...
}
```

The problem is, after I edited an item, everything is updated - the Items collection, the UI, ... - except the CommandParameter of the MenuItems. When I click the Edit-Button the second time, the parameter of the EditItem method is the old Item which should have been removed. This also prevents me from deleting the item, because the collection does not store the old item with the old Title anymore.

How to solve this problem? Can the update of the CommandParameter be triggered somehow? And why does this happen anyway? Aren't the MenuItems rendered with the related ListViewItems?

Comment: I'm not totally sure if I understand you correctly, but you probably want to look at the binding `Mode`.

Comment: When you log the Item parameter in the EditItem method, you will notice that it's title will be e.g. "Item 1" even after it has been removed from the collection and inserted with the new Title "Changed Title" again and although the Title in the UI is correctly "Changed Title". The binding mode doesn't change anything.

Comment: did you solve that problem?

Comment: No, I still don't have a solution.